# How to stop IPython console from placing last line at bottom (?)

Tags: ipython

Please forgive me for the rather unclear title, I didn't know how else to phrase it. Here's the problem I'm facing:

I usually like to have an IPython console separately on while writing Python code so that if there's something I want to understand better (e.g. how a function or method works) I can just type in values and observe the output.

I haven't had this problem before, but I noticed that from some point that whenever I press backspace the console will automatically place the last line at the very bottom of the terminal. For example if I want to write code in this "placement":

[image]

The console will "put the last line at the end of the terminal" whenever I press the backspace key, like so:

[image]

Is there any way to change this behavior so that the console doesn't automatically change the view of the terminal? Thank you.